# The lovely yet evasive page-turn effect in UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Am using a UIPageViewController to display some pages in an iPhone/iPad App. now, when the user presses a button, I want to turn to some random page ; the important thing here is that I want "to show" to the user that am turning through "several" pages. I did look up several answers in Stackoverflow & try them. The best & the only thing am able to simulate is turning "one" page programmatically (i.e. the user sees a single page turn) through this snippet:

```
[self.pageViewController 
         setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithArray:array]  
   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward 
         animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now, I want to show "several" page turns ; i.e. says the user is in page 2 ; then when turning to, say, page 5, currently, it shows only one page turn, though there are "3" pages inbetween page2 & page5.

I tried introducing a NSTimer with a periodic delay. The timer would turn to one page, then delay, then turn to another page, then delay (repeats,say,3 times), so that the user gets the 'effect' of 'several' pages turning.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2f target:self selector:@selector(goToRandomPage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

but this results in only the "last" page turn showing up. That is, say the timer gets fired once to show page 8, then a delay of 0.2, then to show page 3, then a delay of 0.2, then showing page 6. What actually shows up (i.e. what the user sees) is again only one page turn i.e. the last one (turning to page 6).

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to dynamically set the `array` with one page at a time and in `completion` block, try to call the same `setViewControllers` method. Each and every time `setViewControllers` is called the `array` objects should be modified to have the next page alone. `Completion` block should make sure that the current animation is finished and you can start the next animation. Add some condition check inside `completion` block to break this, once it reaches the required page. I haven't tried this, but this should lead you to the right direction.

```
[self.pageViewController 
         setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithArray:array]  
   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward 
         animated:YES completion:^{/* call the same method and modify array */}];
```

Comment: Sounds promising! Let me try & get back! Thank you!

Comment: +1 I didn't try it because it's becoming too slow. Am dropping this idea. Thanks anyways, ACB, for your suggestion!